# Erro de undefined ao ler propriedade 'post' em AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form ng-submit="submit()" ng-controller="myForm">
Nome<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="nome"><br>
Email<br>
<input type="text" ng-model="email"><br>
Senha<br>
<input type="password" ng-model="senha"><br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myForm', ['$scope', function($scope, $http){
        $scope.list = [];
        $scope.submit = function(){
            $http.post('salva.php', {'nome': $scope.nome, 'email': $scope.email, 'senha': $scope.senha})
            then(function(response) {
                console.log('OK '+response);

              }, function(response) {
                console.log('Error '+response);
              });
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

E o seguinte aviso aparece no console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined at n.$scope.submit

[image]

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Seu código do jsfiddle não possui como você está enviando as informações através do Angular para o PHP. Isso é crucial entendermos melhor o problema.

Comment: vc iniciou seu ng-app="myApp" no html ?

Comment: Sim @IvanFerrer, iniciei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adicionar

$http <--- antes do function, como ele não foi declarado, o objeto vai estar undefined, por isso não acha a função .post

```
 .controller('myForm', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    //Código aqui
  }]);
```

Comment: Valeu @RenanDegrandi!
Agora, eu posso usar tanto:

then(function(response) {

}, function(response) {

});

quanto isso:

.success(function(data, status, headers, config){
console.log('Success '+data.status);

})
.error( function(data, status){
console.log('Error '+data.status);

});

Para receber o retorno do php?

Comment: sim, mais na verdade você vai usar .success(function(retorno){}).error(function(retorno){}), para usar o .then você deve utilizar $http({method:'post' .....).then(function(retornoSuccess) ....

Comment: Sendo que o retorno do php tem que ser em json, correto @RenanDegrandi?

Comment: sim exatamente isso.

Comment: Oi @RenanDegrandi, meu json do php está assim:

echo json_encode( array('status' => 1, 'msg' => 'Cadastro efetuado com sucesso!'));

Como pego ele no angular para exibir na tela?

Comment: Não manjo muito de php, por favor pegue o Json que está na variavel (retorno) dentro da função de sucesso e mande, que assim posso tirar sua duvida.

Comment: Seguinte @RenanDegrandi, eu coloquei esses dois comando de console:
console.log(response.status);
console.log(response.msg);

E as respectivas mensagens que aparecem são:
200
undefined

Esse 200 acredito que é uma resposta positivo do status, certo? Já a mensagem, parece que ele não está reconhecendo, que está como msg.

Dê uma olhada no meu git: https://github.com/GugaSevero/CRUD_AngularJS

Comment: exatamente, o status == 200 (Sucess), você precisa pegar o response.data <-- aqui está seu array  (response.data.msg)

Comment: o sucess te retornar um JSON (data, status, headers, config, statusText), dentro do data, está seu retorno (json), para mais .. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Na verdade acredito (Não consegui ver seu código no jsfiddle) que você está fazendo correto na primeira linha mas logo depois tenta pegar os valores no POST. Por padrão o angularJS joga todos as informações em um json no row body do cabeçalho HTTP e para capturar ele com PHP você faz da maneira certa na primeira linha:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Tente:

linha01: `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));`

Comment: pq colocar ("php://input")?

Comment: Oi @Ricardo, reformulei a minha pergunta aqui no post. Por favor, veja se consegue me ajudar.

Comment: @GustavoSevero eu só editei esta resposta para que tive-se a formatação adequada do site não sou o autor dela. espero que consiga uma resolução para o seu problema não conheço nada de angular.

Comment: @Ricardo, eu sabia pouco... Mas dê uma olhada nessa vídeo aulas do Rodrigo Branas, vai aprender muito cara
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb

Answer (score 0):

tenta assim:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
  $request = json_decode($postdata);

  $usrname = $request-usrname;
  $upswd = $request->upswd;
  $email= $request->email;
```

Comment: eu consigo pegar todos os dados fazendo assim com eu coloquei no meu php.
Mas por que fazer isso?

file_get_contents("php://input");
Pq colocar (php://input)?

Comment: colocar o php://input  não sei, acho que é pra colocar em memória e poder converter pra json ja que a funçao json_decode recebe uma String, se não acho q da certo vc pegar o arquivo, converter os bytes em String e depois colocar dentro da função json_decode.

Comment: Oi @EridaniMelo, reformulei a minha pergunta aqui no post. Por favor, veja se consegue me ajudar.

Comment: olá, 
faltou colocar o atributo $http pra poder ser injetado corretamente `...controller('myForm', ['$scope','$http', function($scope, $http){..`.

Comment: reaprendi Angular através de vídeo aulas desse cara https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLQCmSnNFVYnTD5p2fR4EXmtlR6jQJMbPb